# How do I read / parse assembly? How to know what instructions get executed by pre-processor?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, preprocessor, bootloader

I would expect to be able to read it from top to bottom but it seems like nasm has some sort of pre-processor similar to the CPP.

Code I am trying to understand:

```
; Infinite loop (e9 fd ff)
loop:
    jmp loop 

; Fill with 510 zeros minus the size of the previous code
times 510-($-$$) db 0
; Magic number
dw 0xaa55
```

I am confused because I would expect the code to never reach the bottom section which sets 0xaa55 at the last word in the boot sector. I would expect that as it reads the file from top to bottom, when it reaches the `loop: jmp loop`  it would just be stuck there looping forever, it would never reach the bottom code.

Comment: from https://github.com/cfenollosa/os-tutorial/tree/master/01-bootsector-barebones

Comment: An assembler does not execute your code. It generates a binary.

Comment: The assembler proceeds through your entire file (or multiple files with `%include`). You are confusing run-time processing of your code with the build-time processing of your source by the assembler. `jmp` is an instruction that directs the CPU, at run-time, to loop. It does not affect the control flow of the assembling at all, it is simply another item of data as far as the assembler is concerned. NASM does have a preprocessor but the preprocessor also does not run any of the assembly instructions. (It is possible to make the preprocessor loop, but that is done using a `%rep` construct.)

Comment: To make an analogy, just because a cooking recipe has a 'go back to step 2' item, it doesn't mean you are unable to read the rest of the recipe.

Comment: Then how does the computer that executes this (in my case, I run `qemu-system-x86_64 boot_sect_simple.bin` ) not get stuck in the loop?

Comment: @Thomas: You will find it actually does get stuck in the loop. Your qemu terminal/window will not react to any inputs and will not make any outputs if you give it a program like in your example. The only way to get out of the loop is to abort the qemu process, eg using a `kill` command or closing the qemu window.

Comment: The CPU executing this will get stuck, if it ever reaches this code. This kind of code can be found in some situations, like a hard fault that isn't handled. However CPU have alternative control flows, like interrupts, so this could still be correct depending on the situation.

Comment: Ohh I see, so the binary gets created and basically the only useful code that the BIOS executes is this `loop: jmp loop` command. But the reason it is executable as the boot-sector is becaused when nasm created the binary, the last word of the 512 binary was `0xAA55` which is required to make the binary executable by the BIOS in the first place. So basically, that `dw 0xAA55` never even gets run by the computer, however it does get executed by nasm. I this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is *read* by nasm (not executed) and nasm will include this word in the binary accordingly. It is never run by the CPU.

Comment: It's not called "executed" but yes, the `dw` directive is processed by the assembler. In the machine as seen by the ROM-BIOS and your code, the jump loops infinitely. The AA55h is just a signature (in the form of some data) that lives at a certain address in memory. It is never executed by the machine. (If you made an error then the AA55h could be executed, and it would run like the instructions `push bp` then `stosb` in 16-bit mode.)

Comment: @Thomas Try using the `-l` option to `nasm` to see what sort of machine code is generated.  This may make a lot clearer what happens.  NASM does not execute any code, it's not an interpreter.  It translates assembly code into machine code so the compuiter can then execute the machine code.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is correct, you get stuck at the `jmp loop`. The bottom section is never intended for the CPU to actually execute; it just needs to be there for the <del>hardware</del> BIOS to recognize the code as a valid boot sector and run it.

Comment: Not truly the hardware; the *BIOS* software in ROM is what checks for the 0xAA55 boot signature.

Comment: For some reason I thought that the BIOS hadn't loaded yet when you're using a boot sector program

Comment: When an x86 CPU powers on, execution starts from linear address `0xFFFFFFF0`, in unreal mode.  The motherboard should have ROM there.

Comment: That's one small BIOS.

Comment: That's room for a near or far `jmp` to a lower address.  Starting there lets designers make the BIOS as small as they want and still end at the top of physical address space.  Obviously it takes significantly more code to set up an IVT and loop through the storage devices checking for one that has a boot signature.  (And to init all the hardware; on modern x86 systems, firmware switches to protected or long mode, only switching back to real mode if loading a legacy BIOS MBR instead of a UEFI bootloader.)

Comment: Duh! I've used that trick so many times. I guess I'm not sure what is "loaded" since from what I understand a boot sector's job is to load your actual operating system.